# Trouble with Scanner Java

Tags: java

I am writting a program that needs to gather a block of digits and do something with it. But for some reason, the scanner cannot read all the inputted digits. What is wrong?

```
int i = 0;
while (i >=0){
    System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
    i++;
}
```

**Input:**

```
3
100
3
5 75 25
200
7
150 24 79 50 88 345 3
8
8
2 1 9 4 4 56 90 3
```

**Output:**

```
3
100
3
5
75
25
200
7
150
24
79
50
88
345
3
8
8
```

It is missing the last 8 digits. Why is this?

Comment: Does it need the user to press the Return key?

Comment: Are you sure you are showing us the right code and the right input?

Comment: @Jason no, just automatically shows the output

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Yes sir.

Comment: Can you share your actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Getting Only integers *from User*, Scanner will only work **until user enters character or anything except integer in this code.**

```
        try {
            ArrayList<Integer> ar=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("ENTER ANY CHARACTER AND PRESS ENTER TO EXIT!!");
            while(s.hasNextInt())
            {
                ar.add(s.nextInt());
            }

            for(int i:ar)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: How is this related to the original question?

Answer (score 1):

Scanning from System.in requires the user to press the Enter key before the scanner will return the next scanned int.